# How to increase the gap between parallel edges, in Graphviz

Tags: graphviz, dot, pygraphviz, neato

I am rendering a graph which is written in dot language, using the Neato layout engine in graphviz.

My graph consisting with orthogonal lines and, I am facing a problem of lying the parallel edges too close to each other.

Please refer the following diagram

[image]

In above diagram, horizontal parallel edges between node1 and node2 lies too close to each other.

I would be really glad if someone can give me an idea on how to introduce a gap/space in between parallel edges, in order to make the graph looks more clearer.

Following is the dot language code, that I used to render node1 and node2.

```
digraph G { graph[size="70,20.25"] 
splines=ortho;  

edge[style=solid, penwidth="10",labeldistance="10"]; 
node [style="rounded,filled"];

node1 [ pos = "2369.7957583862712,8520.228273052428!", fontsize=300, shape = box, fixedsize=true, width=20, height=20 ];

node2 [ pos="2314.7097320138455,8503.38134510704!", fontsize=300, shape = box, fixedsize=true, width=21, height=28 ];


node1 -> node2[taillabel="99", headlabel="25" , fontsize=100]; 

node1 -> node2[taillabel="29", headlabel="49" , fontsize=100]; 

node1 -> node2[taillabel="36", headlabel="07" , fontsize=100]; 

node1 -> node2[taillabel="62", headlabel="37" , fontsize=100]; 


node2 -> node1[taillabel="251", headlabel="21" , fontsize=100]; 

node2 -> node1[taillabel="140", headlabel="30" , fontsize=100]; 

node2 -> node1[taillabel="21", headlabel="05" , fontsize=100]; 

node2 -> node1[taillabel="35", headlabel="57" , fontsize=100]; 
}
```

Comment: Could you share your code? Re-writing is guesswork and unnecessary effort...

Comment: Code is added to the question.